# iPhone application not running with Distribution Certificate

Tags: iphone

I have a problem regarding running my application with a Distribution certificate. The application will work fine with a Development certificate on my iPod Touch. Once I change the Code Signing Identity to a Distribution certificate and specify an Entitlements file, the application crashes on launch. Is there anything I can do to correct this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, submit it to the app store, and then download it from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, because it keeps crashing, Apple will not approve the application.

Comment: You can't run with the distribution certificate.  It has to be uploaded and approved by Apple and then downloaded from iTunes store before you can run anything that is signed with a distribution cert.  Does it crash for Apple reviewers?

Comment: Yes, it crashes for the reviewers. It also kept crashing when I signed it with an ad-hoc distribution certificate. It should be allowed to work with the ad-hoc because I believe that's meant for distributing to others for testing.

Comment: Then you need to figure out why it's crashing. However, you'll have to do it without the distribution certificate, as that is only for submitting to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compile as release? That should be the same as distribution but use your development certificate.